# Determine size of quadrat by point pattern analysis

Tags: r, spatial

I'm working with a considerably large spatial point dataset that is irregularly spaced. As I want to average the data based on a particular quadrat size (essentially square grids) I was wondering if there is a general rule to determine the raster/grid size. After reading a few articles I ended up finding a formula which states that in 2 dimensions (2D), for square quadrats/grid/raster, the length of the side of a quadrat would be:

```
√(2A/N)
```

where, A= area, & N = number of points. If my data is scattered in 3D, say for example data collected from ocean has X, Y coordinates as well as depth, Z, what rule of thumb should be applied? Reference to a R statistical package to do such analysis would be appreciated. I tried "spatstat" package where functions like quadratcount(), quadrat.test() exist, but I'm looking for something that would suggest quadrat size based on the nature (distance, number of samples, denisty, etc.) of the data.

Comment: Because your use of terms like "quadrat," "grid," and "dimension" leaves me totally lost, I suspect you might be using them in ways that are unfamiliar to me (and therefore to others). Would you be able to explain them? Are you perhaps simply trying to summarize the point data into a raster ("grid") format? Regardless, it is not at all apparent why you would want to do that. (Which I suspect is why you can't find any guidance: the answers depend on your objectives at least as much as they depend on any perceptible properties of the data.)  What will the purpose of this averaging be?

Comment: @whuber: yes, I'd like to rasterize, the purpose is to compare one data with another.

Comment: The answer depends on many factors related to the nature of the two datasets, their inherent accuracy (especially relative positional accuracy), and the kind of comparison you will be making.  There are many "rules of thumb" about this that are totally off base, so you are best off using your own informed judgment and statistical knowledge. Some discussion related to this has occurred on the GIS site at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/67429, http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/40918, and http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/8900. For an algorithm see my post at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17551.